# Modal Image with CSS and JavaScript

Tags: html

In the following code, how do I adjust the code so that I can display more than 1 picture?

I am new to HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. You have to write what you tried. No one write pure codes for you.

Comment: for looping through a range of elements I suggest using jQuery class selector not pure JavaScript.

Comment: Extracted code from http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img and added it to the question. stripped out all none relevant CSS and JS. Also removed JS and CSS tags.

Answer (score 3):

My answer would be different depending on your purpose. So what do you need that for? Are you learing javascript? In production enviroment it would be easier and more prespective to use [jquery](https://jquery.com/) lib.

Anyway. This is pure javascript solution. All you have to do is to distict image elements with selectors and copy event handles (.onclick).

```
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to create a modal (dialog box) that is hidden by default.</p>
<p>We use JavaScript to trigger the modal and to display the current image inside the modal when it is clicked on. Also note that we use the value from the image's "alt" attribute as an image caption text inside the modal.</p>

<img id="myImg1" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img id="myImg2" src="http://blog.tripwolf.com/de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/6059394277_55950beb55_b.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the images
var img1 = document.getElementById('myImg1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('myImg2');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

//handle click for myImg1
img1.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
//handle click for myImg2
img2.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}



// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
```